# Gitlab to remote docker - continuous development

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, continuous-deployment

I'm looking for a solution to organize a continuous deployment process, using Gitlab and Docker.

The idea is simple: when I create a git merge on the dev branch, Gitlab export/update an image in a remote docker container.

Actually, I just created some images manually with a Dockerfile to update manually a local docker but I would like to automize this process in a remote docker.

How can I do that?

Comment: The gitlab documentation includes extensive examples of how to build and store docker images using their CI system.

Comment: I realize that repositories has not been activated by my gitlab's admin. So I'll try with the CI/CD features yes.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/rezshar/wordpress-CICD-sample) It's a simple project for deploying CI-CD on Gitlab, It may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link, It helped me a lot!